# float precision in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change a number in the df but the Pandas converts it to a floor number.

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

I change a number:

```
df['B'][1] = 1.2
```

it gives:

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   1
2   3   6
```

instead of:

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   1.2
2   3   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has some rather complex view/copy behavior.   Your syntax assigns a new value to a *copy* of the data, leaving the original unchanged.  You can update the value in place via:

```
df.loc[1, "B"] = 1.2
```

result:

```
   A    B
0  1  4.0
1  2  1.2
2  3  6.0
```